# why I can't create my array object inside function?

Tags: java, arrays, object, instance-variables

I have declare an array of String in my class without initialise it, then I create a function that fill this array called "FillFacts". the problem is when I call the function that should return my array it return NullPointerException.
the question is how I can initialise my array inside a function because I had tested to initialise it at declaration section like this :

```
private String[] facts = {"fact1", "fact2", "fact3"};
```

and it works but I don't want to use it like this.

Code Source :

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Facts {

private String[] facts;
private String[] colors;

private String fact, color;
private Random random = new Random();
private int random_number;

public void Facts() {

    this.random = new Random();
    this.random_number = 0;

    FillFacts();
    FillColors();
}

public void FillFacts() {

    facts = new String[] {"smartphone android has a home button", "every Iphone has a memory in his heart!", "cubes can be rotated in 180 degree", "banana has a yellow color", "wacom tablet are linked with usb cable"};
}

public void FillColors() {

    colors = new String[] {"#34495e", "#3498db", "#1abc9c", "#e74c3c", "#f1c40f", "#95a5a6", "#d35400"};
}

public String PickRandomFact() {

    random_number = random.nextInt(facts.length) ;
    fact = facts[random_number];
    return fact;
}

public String PickRandomColor() {

    random_number = random.nextInt(colors.length);
    color = colors[random_number];
    return color;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void Facts()` is not a constructor, so it's not executed when you create an instance of `Facts` (which is why `FillFacts` and `FillColors` are not executed). A constructor doesn't have a return type.

Change

```
public void Facts()
```

to

```
public Facts()
```

Comment: Can you tell me how did you debug my code fast ?? do you know some debugging tips you can tell me please because I have nightmare with it yersterday and you just resolve it.

Comment: @user21959 I looked at your code, and your array initialization looked correct, so I gave it another look and tried to think what would prevent your FillFacts and FillColors methods from being executed. That was when I noticed the invalid constructor declaration. Of course you could have found it easily if you ran your code in a debugger and put a break point in the Facts method, which would have shown you that it's never executed.

Comment: Thank you again for your great explanation and your respond.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `constructor` void:

```
 public void Facts() {
```

To like this :

```
 public Facts() {
```

Comment: `FillFacts` initializes an instance member, so it doesn't require a return type.